# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - change to setContentView()

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am getting a fairly generic error for what I think is something very unusual. I am learning Android Studio using a boot called [Android Programming for Beginners](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/android-programming-for/9781785883262/index.html) and I have come to a section that firstly shows me how to set up a virtual instance on my PC using the built in emulator (downloading intel HAXM to create a tablet app), then create a new layout, give the layout a name and change the following code so when I run the app on a virtual device the new layout will be the opening screen:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_Activity);
```

a few things to note:

- I have a Galaxy S3 which I have used as an emulator to run my apps
  and has been working fine up to this point.
- my CPU is an Intel i5-4650 which will apparently not support the
  visualization add on installed from the SDK manager, I tried to
  install this from the Intel website and it said my CPU will not
  support (I don't think this is the issue here but I only started
  having issues once I installed/uninstalled this update) I have
  created a project with a new layout and re-pointed the setContentView
  in previous chapters to this layout and it has worked.
- I have completely reinstalled Android Manager and it has failed to
  fix. Can anyone see if the book is out of date to achieve what I want
  or am I looking at this completely the wrong way.
- I also have Genymotion set up on a virtual server which has also bee running fine up until now.
- I have not been able to get the android build in emulator to work on any device.
- I have Android Manager on a laptop, I have set up GIT to link my jobs and this problem seems to have happened to the lap top too. It is an old laptop and almost certainly does not support the visualization.

I get the error below when I try to run the app on any virtual device, my S3 or the Genymotion server. I tried to recreate new a project starting from scratch to force it to work, it will work once and then it stops.

The device i am running the app on will say that the "system UI not responding" and the error below appears in the Android Manager.

I have posted what I think is required but I can add anything else that is required.  I feel like the solution to this problem is something really daft that I have either missed or the book is slightly out of date (as these things tend to progress very quickly).  I also feel that the visualization is not the issue unless something is cached somewhere.

Thanks you an advanced.

Error code

```
03-21 21:51:58.009 28871-28871/com.packtpub.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packtpub.myapplication/com.packtpub.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.packtpub.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the activity_main.java code - I have created a layout called adc and changed the line to setContentView(R.layout.adc);

```
package com.packtpub.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adc);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_Main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.packtpub.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.packtpub.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

adc.xml code - this is the generic code. I have changed nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.packtpub.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update activity_Main.xml name to acitivity_main then
    Change

```
 setContentView(R.layout.adc);

to this

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Yeah, this will work if I want activity_main.xml to start when I launch the app, I want adc.xml to start when I launch the app.

Comment: Your tool bar exist in activity_main not in adc

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what that means. I am learning android studio at the moment and the error I am getting is one that I cannot decipher and feel i shouldn't be getting the error. Can you explain what you mean? Can you highlight what code needs changing? Thanks

Comment: You are getting Toolbar using this line

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

before this line you use layout adc and your toolbar is not in adc it is in activity_main

So when you try to get toolbar from adc then you are getting null
thats why you got error NullPointerException

Comment: Gotcha, Ok I will give that a whirl and report back.  So does that mean I need to add "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"  into adc.xml?

Comment: If you add toolbar in your adc layout it will work and

If you replace setContentView(R.layout.adc);  to
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); then it should work as well

Comment: Ok, sorry to be a complete noob and I really appreciate your time.  Thanks again.

Comment: No Problem i am here to help you out

Comment: Brilliant, makes perfect sense and got it working.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have set the content view to `R.layout.adc` which does not contain the `ToolBar` or the `FloatingActionButton` hence your app will crash at the following lines of

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Include them in your adc layout and it should work fine or in case you do not need the above view remove the following code from your MainActivity.java class

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's great, i'll give that a try. Does this need to be added to any .xml layout that I want to show on start up or does it need to be added to all of the .xml layouts that are included in my package? Thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks you for you help. I was able to remove the code and port the information over tot eh correct xml file.  Thanks again.